# How to change the image positions in bootstrap html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'd like to know how to replace the position for the  image from right side to left side  and the  text from right side to left side

my code is :-

```
 <div class="section margin-top_50">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 layout_padding_2">
                    <div class="full">
                        <div class="heading_main text_align_left">
                           <h2><span> TT </span> ERP </h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="full">
                          <p> TEST </p>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="full">
                        <img src="images/img2.png" alt="#" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of what's the output you're currently getting, and explain the one you want.

Comment: i just want to change the position of the image from right side to left side ..

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of what's the output you're currently getting, and explain the one you want may be it will solve your problem i think add float-right class to image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go. to change the text from right to left just use the class `text-left` and if you want it to the right use `text-right` do the same for the image container

```
  <div class="section margin-top_50">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 layout_padding_2">
                    <div class="full">
                        <!-- added class text-left -->
                        <div class="heading_main text_align_left text-left">
                            <h2><span> TT </span> ERP </h2>
                        </div>
                        <!-- added class text-left -->
                        <div class="full text-left">
                            <p> TEST </p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!-- added class text-left -->
                    <div class="full text-left">
                        <img src="images/img2.png" alt="#" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the elements should be helpful.

```html
<div class="section margin-top_50">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Was in 2nd previously -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="full">
          <img src="images/img2.png" alt="#" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Was in 1st previously -->
      <div class="col-md-6 layout_padding_2">
        <div class="full">
          <div class="heading_main text_align_left">
            <h2><span> TT </span> ERP </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="full">
            <p> TEST </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's ok for the image , but what about the text ? still in right side  .. i want to left side

Comment: it's ok for the image , but what about the text ? still in left side  .. i want to right side

Comment: @mk92 let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> if you only want to show image in left side and text in right side then the image column should be there after the text column

```
<div class="section margin-top_50">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="full">
                    <img src="images/img2.png" alt="#" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 layout_padding_2">
                <div class="full">
                    <div class="heading_main text_align_left">
                       <h2><span> TT </span> ERP </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="full">
                      <p> TEST </p>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>       
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```